# Does a one-to-one relationship in Laravel always need first()?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a one-to-one relationship between User and UserSettings models,

But (after `$user = auth()->user()`) when I try `$user->settings()->something` it throws an `Undefined property` error.

It's gone when I use `$user->settings()->first()->something`...

My question is, is this how it's supposed to work? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried `$user->settings->something` could you please share you settings() method from your User model

Comment: @RonakDhoot Thank you! using `$user->settings->something` instead of `$user->settings()->something` fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly run `$user->settings()->something`.

Because when you call `$user->settings()`, it just return [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.html) object.

So it is not the model's object, you need to take the **model's object** and call its attribute like this.

```php
$user->settings()->first()->something;
```

---

### Dynamic Properties

Since you have one-to-one relationship between `User` and `UserSettings`.

If you have a one-to-one relationship in your User model:

```php
public function settings()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserSettings', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

According to [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

> Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record using Eloquent's **dynamic properties**. Dynamic properties allow you to access relationship methods as if they were properties defined on the model:
>
> Eloquent will **automatically load the relationship** for you, and is even smart enough to **know whether to call the get** (for one-to-many relationships) **or first** (for one-to-one relationships) method. It will then **be accessible** via a dynamic property by the same name as the relation.

So you can use eloquent's [dynamic properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#dynamic-properties) like this:

```php
$user->settings->something; // settings is the dynamic property of $user.
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will give you a result of collection.

```
$user->settings;
```

So calling 'something' is not available or it will return you of null, unless you get the specific index of it.

```
$user->settings()->something
```

while this one works because you used  first() to get the first data of collection and accessed the properties of it .

```
$user->settings()->first()->something
```

The first method returns the first element in the collection that passes a given truth test
see docs here [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-first)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the user `settings` itself simply do this:

```
$user->settings
```

Then you can get the fields of the settings doing this:

```
$user->settings->something
```

---

When you do this `$user->settings()` you can chain query after that. E.g.

```
$user->settings()->where('something', 'hello')->first()
```

That's why the output of `$user->settings` and `$user->settings()->first()` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Auth only gives you user info;

Try the following code:

```
$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);//and then 
$user->settings->something;
```